# Evaluating the volume of a torus formed by rotating a region about a horizontal axis using shells.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, volume

Using the method of cylindrical shells, find the volume of the shape created by revolving the region $x^2+(y-5)^2=4$ about $y=-1$.

A cylindrical shell is given by: $2\pi v f(v) \ dv$

I solve $x^2+(y-5)^2=4$ for $y$ such that $y=\pm\sqrt{10y-y^-21}$.

The region bounded by $y=\sqrt{10y-y^-21}$ goes from $5 \leq y \leq 7$, which is the top half of the circle. By its symmetry, multiply by $2$ to find the remaining area.

This implies the volume is given by $4\pi\displaystyle\int_{5}^{7}(y+1)\sqrt{10y-y^-21}{\ dy}$.

However, when evaluated, this is different from what is calculated [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume%20of%20rotation%20of%20x%5E2%2B%28y-5%29%5E2%3D4%2C%20about%20y%3D-1).

Where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use

$\displaystyle V=\int_3^72\pi r(y)h(y)dy=\int_3^7 2\pi(y+1) \cdot2\sqrt{4-(y-5)^2}dy=4\pi\int_3^7(y+1)\sqrt{4-(y-5)^2}dy$

$\hspace{.4 in}$since $x=\pm\sqrt{4-(y-5)^2}\implies h(y)=2\sqrt{4-(y-5)^2}$.

(Notice that we can't double the volume generated by the top half of the circle, since the volume generated by the top half is greater than the volume generated by the bottom half of the circle.)

---

As a check, by Pappus's Theorem we have $V=A(2\pi\rho)=(\pi\cdot2^2)(2\pi\cdot6)=48\pi^2.$

Comment: My integral does not go from $3$ to $7$, it goes from $5$ to $7$. Are you saying "I have" or, "I should have"? Your language is ambiguous.

Comment: @Alex Sorry - I will edit my answer to make it clearer. (See the remark about using symmetry.)

Comment: Note that if the question had asked to find the volume by the "washer" or "annulus" method (that is, the "disk" method with a hole in the middle of each disk), you _could_ find the volume of the half of the torus where $0<x<2$ and correctly double that, due to symmetry.

Comment: @DavidK You're right -that's a good observation.